# Using lag in mutate() for rolling values forward for the created column

Tags: r, lag, dplyr, clickstream

I am trying to specify sessions in a click stream data. I group rows based on months and userId and try to create another variable session, that looks at diff_days column, and increase by on if thats > 0.00209 and stays as the previous value otherwise. So basically I am trying to create session variable and use the lag version on it at the same time. The fist row in a group is always session = 1.

So take for example this data is one of the groups from group_by:

```
ID Month diff_days
2    0     NA
2    0     0.0002
2    0     0.001
2    0     0.01
2    0     0.00034
2    0     0.1
2    0     0.3
2    0     0.00005
```

and I want to create session variable within each group like this:

```
ID Month diff_days session
2   0    NA        1
2   0    0.0002    1
2   0    0.001     1    
2   0    0.01      2
2   0    0.00034   2
2   0    0.1       3
2   0    0.3       4
2   0    0.00005   4
```

The code that I am using and not giving the right answer:

```
data <- data %>% group_by(ID, Month)
%>% mutate(session =  ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1 ,
ifelse(diff_days < 0.0209, lag(session) , lag(session) + 1))) %>% ungroup()
```

I have been struggling with this for quite some time so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cumsum` on the logical vector after grouping by 'ID', 'Month'.  Create a logical vector `diff_days[-1] >= 0.00209` (removed the first observation which is `NA` and appended `TRUE` as the first one.  Then, get the cumulative sum, so that for every TRUE value, it gets added 1.

```
data %>% 
   group_by(ID, Month) %>%
   mutate(session = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff_days[-1] >= 0.00209)))
# A tibble: 8 x 4
# Groups:   ID, Month [1]
#     ID Month diff_days session
#  <int> <int>     <dbl>   <int>
#1     2     0  NA             1
#2     2     0   0.0002        1
#3     2     0   0.001         1
#4     2     0   0.01          2
#5     2     0   0.00034       2
#6     2     0   0.1           3
#7     2     0   0.3           4
#8     2     0   0.00005       4
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. If its not too much trouble, could you please explain the cumsum part?

Comment: @user2843669  Thanks, I added some explanation.  Hope it helps